# how to hanlde error if xml xpath does not exist -UFT/QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

how can we check that the xpath in xml does not exist :

I have to perform text file to xml data comparison , XML file contains several transactions. some transactions contains tag while some does not.
since i have understanding of these tags, i have captured the xpaths.

there is a situation when data exists in text file but corresponding tag in xml transaction is missing.

in report i am printing data values in both file.
i want to print blank in case xpath does not exist or tag not present in a transaction. ?? how to handle it.

for Missing tag UFT throwing error : Failed to retrieve the item. The index is out of range.

```
     <Transaction>
                <xyz>alpha-4141</xyz>
                <abc>500005000002300</abc>
                <pqr>testing4141</pqr>
                <lmn>ED</lmn>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
                <xyz>alpha-4142</xyz>
                <abc>900005000002400</abc>
                <lmn>ED</lmn>
    </Transaction>
```

text file data :

Trans_start alpha-4141  500005000002300 testing4141  ED Trans_end

Trans_start alpha-4142  900005000002400 testing4141  ED Trans_end

code :
      `Set xmlObj = XMLUtil.CreateXML()
      xmlObj.LoadFile("E:\QTP-UFT\testing.xml")
      Set xyz=xmlObj.ChildElementsByPath("//Transaction//xyz")`

To get value :

```
xmlvalueviaXpath=xpath.Item(index).Value()
```

Comment: That looks more like VB6 than VB.NET to me. Is it VB6? Or maybe VBA?

Comment: You can use `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0` to handle and process the error gracefully.